# Проблема цвета гиперссылок

Tags: html, css

Помогите с HTML! Кто сталкивался с проблемой смены цвета гиперссылок? Ставлю теги смены цвета:

- цвет ссылки - зеленый
- цвет ссылки при нажатии - красный
- цвет той, на которой уже побывал, - желтый

Почему-то работает только цвет при нажатии! Остальные стоят стандартные, по умолчанию! Помогите, кто сталкивался...

Comment: Приведите код css и html-код ссылок

Answer (score 2):

в CSS файле указать: (можно и внутри тегов)

```
a:link{
color:#цвет_в_16-ричном_виде
}
```

:link - активная (синяя)
:visited - посещенная (фиолетовая)
:hover - при наведении
:active - момент щелчка 
если в в CSS файле, то должно примениться ко всем ссылкам

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы лучше код прописали бы, наверное, ошибка в коде, другого не может быть.

```
A:link {color: black}
A:visited {color: red}
A:active {color: blue}
A:hover {color: white;}
```

Comment: <body link=green>,<body alink=red>,<body vlink=yellow> - стандартные писал...

Comment: а если к примеру <br /><body link=#00FF00 alink=#FF0000 vlink=yellow><br />Тело<br /> </body>

Answer (score 1):

Может дело в порядке указания цвета. Я обычно использую порядок такой: link, visited, hover, active. (Легко запомнить **L**o**V**e-**HA**te - любить-ненавидеть.)

Comment: проблема в том, что видимо для каждого линка указан свой боди))

Comment: Кстати как вариант... Вот спасибо от души!!Непременно попробую, а для одного линка кстати указаны данные цвета!Я даже и не ожидал столь бурной реакции!